# @BeforeMethod implementaion issue

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, junit

I want to implement BeforeMethod Annotation for specific test, it's getting implemented before every test can anybody know how resolve this issue!!! even tried with groups!!

Thanks

Comment: @BeforeMethod is meant for setup-methods that do the boilerplate stuff that is common for all tests. it's considered very bad practice to have temporal coupling between your tests, it drastically reduces the usefulness of the suite. how come you need to run this test first?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is move out the test that doesn't need the `@Before` method into a separate test class. Also if you have some other code common to the tests you may move it into a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to call the method explicitly in your test.

```
@Test
public void yourTest() {
  beforeMethod();
  //your test
}
```